# how to create a geom_bar graph without cumulative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Something like this

[image]

I am trying to make stacked bar graph but don't want cumulative values

```
 ggplot() + 
   geom_bar(data = era, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Criteria), 
     stat="identity", alpha = 0.5) +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("red3","orange3", "green3", "yellow3")) +
   geom_point(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy, y=median_era, group=1), 
     shape = "|", size = 20, color ="brown1") +
   geom_point(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy, y=mean_era, group=1), 
     shape = "|", size = 20, color = "coral4") +
   geom_point(data = searches, aes(x=Strategy, y=value, group=2), 
     shape = "|", size = 20, color = "darkblue") + 
   coord_flip()
```

My Output vs desired output
[image]

Here is my data set

## data era

```
era <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("18.Apr", "18.Feb", "18.Jan"
), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("GrossNetEquity", 
"GrossTotalEquityPerfAttr", "LongNetEquity", "LongTotalEquity", 
"NetEquity", "NetEquityPerfAttr", "NetTotalEquity", "ShortNetEquity", 
"ShortTotalEquity", "TotalNetEquity"), class = "factor"), value = c(89.1, 
86.4, 79.6, 92.3, 89.6, 83, -28.1, -28, -26.9, -29.5, -29.5, 
-27.6, 61, 58.4, 52.7, 62.8, 60.1, 55.4, 117.2, 114.4, 106.5, 
121.8, 119.1, 110.6, 1.2, -2.1, 1.8, 1.4, -2.1, 1.9), Criteria = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Above 70", 
"Below 45", "Between 45 & 60", "Between 60 & 70"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"variable", "value", "Criteria"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

## data searches

```
searches <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), .Label = c("10.Apr", "10.Aug", 
  "10.Dec", "10.Feb", "10.Jan", "10.Jul", "10.Jun", "10.Mar", "10.May", 
  "10.Nov", "10.Oct", "10.Sep", "11.Apr", "11.Aug", "11.Dec", "11.Feb", 
  "11.Jan", "11.Jul", "11.Jun", "11.Mar", "11.May", "11.Nov", "11.Oct", 
  "11.Sep", "12.Apr", "12.Aug", "12.Dec", "12.Feb", "12.Jan", "12.Jul", 
  "12.Jun", "12.Mar", "12.May", "12.Nov", "12.Oct", "12.Sep", "13.Apr", 
  "13.Aug", "13.Dec", "13.Feb", "13.Jan", "13.Jul", "13.Jun", "13.Mar", 
  "13.May", "13.Nov", "13.Oct", "13.Sep", "14.Apr", "14.Aug", "14.Dec", 
  "14.Feb", "14.Jan", "14.Jul", "14.Jun", "14.Mar", "14.May", "14.Nov", 
  "14.Oct", "14.Sep", "15.Apr", "15.Aug", "15.Dec", "15.Feb", "15.Jan", 
  "15.Jul", "15.Jun", "15.Mar", "15.May", "15.Nov", "15.Oct", "15.Sep", 
  "16.Apr", "16.Aug", "16.Dec", "16.Feb", "16.Jan", "16.Jul", "16.Jun", 
  "16.Mar", "16.May", "16.Nov", "16.Oct", "16.Sep", "17.Apr", "17.Aug", 
  "17.Dec", "17.Feb", "17.Jan", "17.Jul", "17.Jun", "17.Mar", "17.May", 
  "17.Nov", "17.Oct", "17.Sep", "18.Apr", "18.Feb", "18.Jan", "18.Jun", 
  "18.Mar", "18.May", "7.Aug", "7.Dec", "7.Jul", "7.Nov", "7.Oct", 
  "7.Sep", "8.Apr", "8.Aug", "8.Dec", "8.Feb", "8.Jan", "8.Jul", 
  "8.Jun", "8.Mar", "8.May", "8.Nov", "8.Oct", "8.Sep", "9.Apr", 
  "9.Aug", "9.Dec", "9.Feb", "9.Jan", "9.Jul", "9.Jun", "9.Mar", 
  "9.May", "9.Nov", "9.Oct", "9.Sep"), class = "factor"), variable = 
  structure(1:10, .Label = c("LongNetEquity", 
  "LongTotalEquity", "ShortNetEquity", "ShortTotalEquity", "NetEquity", 
  "NetTotalEquity", "GrossNetEquity", "TotalNetEquity", "NetEquityPerfAttr", 
  "GrossTotalEquityPerfAttr"), class = "factor"), value = c(88, 
  92.3, -28.1, -29.3, 58.8, 63, 116.1, 121.6, -1.2, -1.2), Criteria = c("Above 
  70", "Above 70", "Below 45", "Below 45", "Between 45 & 60", "Between 60 & 
  70","Above 70", "Above 70", "Below 45", "Below 45")), .Names = c("Date", 
  "variable", "value", "Criteria"), row.names = c(1L, 109L, 217L, 
  325L, 433L, 541L, 649L, 757L, 865L, 973L), class = "data.frame")
```

## data newtable

```
newtable <- structure(list(Strategy = structure(c(3L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 
1L, 10L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("GrossNetEquity", "GrossTotalEquityPerfAttr", 
"LongNetEquity", "LongTotalEquity", "NetEquity", "NetEquityPerfAttr", 
"NetTotalEquity", "ShortNetEquity", "ShortTotalEquity", "TotalNetEquity"
), class = "factor"), median_era = c(77.35, 82.65, -34.1, -35.55, 
41.45, 46.35, 114.2, 119.8, 1.25, 1.4), mean_era = c(77.74, 84.51, 
-34.42, -36.44, 43.26, 48.07, 112.2, 121, 1.051, 1.148)), .Names = c("Strategy", 
"median_era", "mean_era"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What does your data look like? Make sure to share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run and see the code. It seems you might have multiple `value` values for each `variable`. If you don't want to sum them, it's unclear how you want to combine them.

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997754/ggplot2-bar-plot-order-fill-as-in-data?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Using the `group` aesthetic might help.

Comment: I added my dataset as advised @MrFlick

Comment: @aosmith i try using group function but values are coming like 1 to 300 where as in my data there is no value above 150

Comment: @MrFlick I shared data of era and thats the table I m concerned at this point. Requirements for graph are  take all the values and show bar graph based on that and then give different color to the bar graph based on criteria. But my property is i m getting graph on cumulative basis .

Comment: If i take out all the `geom_point` parts that wont work, I get a plot with the values you expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWsh.png So there must be something going on other that what you've shown us.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the desired output, but using `group = row.names(era)` seems to plot each observation in a stack in the order of the dataset instead of grouping all the `fill` stacks together.

Comment: @MrFlick I added other two datasets. In my data lastegest value is not more than 150 not sure why you are getting 300

Comment: @aosmith I am trying to get exact values in a graph and apply conditions to them i.e. if i have 1,2,3,4 values then i want bar graph to be on 1,2,3,4 axis rather than accumulated to 10 axis and then apply condition on that axis. I hope I able to clarify the requirements. Thank you for all your help

Comment: Well, for example, your dataset has three values for GrossNetEquity (see `subset(era, variable=="GrossNetEquity")`): 117,2, 114.4, 106.5. They all have the same criteria ("Above 70"). Since they are all in the same group, R adds those values together to get a single value. What else would you like to do with them? At the end of the day, the bar can only have one height. I'm not really sure what you are expecting.

Comment: @MrFlick i want to take all the historical values for each variable and then create bar graph from minimum to maximum value and give different colors depending upon condition i.e. > 45 - yellow, 45-60 - blue, 60-70-orange,<70 red.  and then show median,mean and current value in it. So like in GrossNetEquity i need graph from 106 to 117 only and then add mean,median and current value in it.

Comment: @aosmith  Thank you for all your help. Actually group worked with position = dodge. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = era, aes(x=variable, y=value,fill =Criteria, group= variable),stat="identity",position = "dodge",alpha = 0.5, width =0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red3","orange3","green3","yellow3")) +
  geom_point(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy,y=median_era,group=1),shape = "|", size = 5,color ="brown1")+
  geom_text(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy, y=median_era, label = paste("Median",median_era)), 
            size = 3, vjust = 2, hjust = -0.5,color = "brown1")+
  geom_point(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy,y=mean_era,group=1),shape = "|", size = 5,color = "coral4")+
  geom_text(data = newtable, aes(x=Strategy, y=mean_era, label = paste("Mean",mean_era)), 
            size = 3, vjust = 4, hjust = -0.5,color ="coral4")+
  geom_point(data = searches, aes(x=Strategy,y=value,group=2),shape = "|", size = 5,color = "darkblue")+
  geom_text(data = searches, aes(x=Strategy, y=value, label = paste("Current Value",value)), 
            size = 3, vjust = 0, hjust = 0.25,color = "darkblue")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
```